# how to generate a new http session id without close internet explorer in Servlet

Tags: servlets

In my system, after user login the page, I want to generate a new http session id without close internet explorer.

I write the code like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{


    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    System.out.println("session id:"+session.getId());



    session.invalidate();

    deleteCookie( request.getCookies(),request,response);

    session = request.getSession();

    System.out.println("new session id:"+session.getId());

} 

private void deleteCookie(Cookie[] cookies,HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse response){
    logger.debug("Delete cookie");


    int cookieLenght = cookies.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < cookieLenght; i++) {
        Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        cookie.setPath("/");

        response.addCookie(cookie);

    }

 }
```

Even I invalidate the session , delete the cookie ,get a new session, but the session Id is still the same.   I do not know why. Is there any solution to generate a new session id without close the internet Explorer？

Comment: regenerating as you described works for me well. I get different session ids just after invalidate(I don't touch cookies). What server are you using. I have tested this on GlassFish

Comment: Looks fine to me too. Although just calling `session.invalidate()` was been sufficient. The servletcontainer will worry about cookies.